# how get the name of the first array1bits from Array storebits?

Tags: java

i have array the element in this array type is Array .
how can get the name of first element from Array?

```
int[] storebits[] = {array1bits, array2bits, array3bits, array4bits};
```

how to get the name of the first array1bits  from  Array `storebits`?

Comment: What is the name of an array element? I think what you want is `storebits[0]`.

Comment: Arrays inside `storebits` have no names, only values. Generally speaking, names are compile-time things. As far as local variables are concerned, names disappear after compiling.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a Map ? It can associate a name with a value (or a value with a name).

Comment: Variable names are only available at compile time. They are no longer available at run time. Why do you need the name of the array? You can access it with `storebits[0]`.

Comment: @MoatasemKamal What are you trying to do? What's the program that this is a part of?

Comment: ok  @dasblinkenlight    int array1[] = {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1};
        int array2[] = {-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1};
        int array3[] = {-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1};
        int array4[] = {-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1};
        int[] storeAllArray[] = {array1, array2, array3, array4};   i want enter storeArray in loop and make scanner when user enter array1 , compare it with the item of storeArray , how make this ?

Comment: @MoatasemKamal Edit the question instead.

Comment: i want make Code Division Multiplexing Access CDMA

Comment: @Bubletan make scanner when user enter array1 , compare it with the item of storeArray , how make this ?

Comment: @Bubletan i don't Understand your question

Answer (score 0):

If it's important to associate a name to the first element of your integer array, then you'll either need a parallel array of strings that has corresponding name entries, or you would need an object that contains a name and and your integer and have an array of those. Another alternative, which has already been mentioned in the comments, is to have a Map where the name is associated with the array.